# How to read a WFS published through QGIS server with Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, wfs, qgis-server

I would like to read a WFS published using QGIS server, with the plugin Leaflet-WFST but an error occurs when the plugin is trying to read the geometry.

Error :

> uncaught exception: unknown child element Point

Result of the WFS POST request:

```
<gml:boundedBy xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <gml:coordinates cs="," ts=" ">-4.07446736,52.4326541
            -4.07446736,52.4326541</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<qgs:geometry xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">
    <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <coordinates xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" cs="," ts=" ">-4.07446736,52.4326541</coordinates>
    </Point>
</qgs:geometry>
<qgs:_URI xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">uuid:858df484-a17e-45b0-b740-0639f530d946</qgs:_URI>
<qgs:SITE_DETAILS_OBSERVER xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml"/>
<qgs:crationdate xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">2019-01-24T13:35:37</qgs:crationdate>
<qgs:diamtrunk xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">20</qgs:diamtrunk>
<qgs:heighttrunkmesure xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">1.3</qgs:heighttrunkmesure>
<qgs:species xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">Pinus-sylvestris</qgs:species>
<qgs:circumference xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">62.8318530717959</qgs:circumference>
<qgs:crownxaxis xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">3</qgs:crownxaxis>
<qgs:crownyaxis xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">1</qgs:crownyaxis>
<qgs:crownorientation xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/gml">20.67</qgs:crownorientation>.
```

Additional information:

Points came from a PostGIS database (postgresql 9.5 postgis 2.2) then publish using QGIS 2.18.16

The WFS can be read perfectly using a remote computer and QGis desktop

The GetCapabilities of the service: http://54.38.33.23/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&version=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/home/sebastien/odkResult/indTrees.qgs

Leaflet code:

```
var layer2=new L.WFS({
                url: 'http://54.38.33.23/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/sebastien/odkResult/mangroveTrees.qgs',
                //typeNS:"",
                geometryField:'geometry',
                typeName: 'ind_trees',
                crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
                style: {
                  color: 'red',
                  weight: 3
                }
            }).addTo(mymap)
```

Comment: Can you read other WFS services using the plug in?

Comment: When I try to access the WFS from this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYMJym i get a CORS error in the browser console (after pressing F12). This may also be contributing factor to the problem.

Comment: Thank you but is more a copy paste error when I wrote the question. I edited the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155959)

Comment: I can read other WFS using the plugin as suggested in the turorial. But every WFS that I tried to read came from mapserver or geoserver I did not find any QGIS server to test.

Comment: I use the same server to publish the data and to read it so I do not have CORS issues. When I look at the http response I can see that I access the WFS. The issue is when the plugin try to read the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same challenge. I found a difference between qgis wfs and geoserver wfs outputs. geoserver element.tagName returned "gml:Polygon" where qgis returned "Polygon". If you know you will only ever use qgis to publish your wfs then I suppose you could revise line 876 of Leaflet-WFST 1.2.0

from: `var parser = this.parsers[element.tagName];`

to: `var parser = this.parsers["gml:".concat(element.tagName)];`

It is working for me but I haven't tested much. It may well break something else.